# Where should I place tokens via Builder resolved from another server?

Tags: android-netrunner

I've got several ices on a remote server. On the top of them - rezzed [Builder](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07016). I've got rezzed [Wormhole](https://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Wormhole), protecting another server (HQ, for example). The runner makes a run on HQ and faces the [Wormhole](https://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Wormhole). It's subroutine is triggered (resolve a subroutine on another piece of rezzed ice) and I decide to resolve the [Builder's](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07016) subroutine. On what server's ice can I put the advancement token? HQ or the server with the [Builder](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07016) on top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Wormhole's subroutine to resolve a subroutine on Builder, you place the advancement counter on a piece of ICE protecting the server Builder is on. Builder is resolving it's own subroutine, not Wormhole.

Comment: Wormhole's subroutine: "resolve a subroutine on another piece of rezzed ice". Builder is another rezzed piece of ice. So, I think, I can resolve a subroutine on it in the case of triggering subroutine on the Wormhole.

Comment: I've improved the question.

Comment: Ok, I see, you've edited the answer. Do you have any references to the rules? I feel you are right, also we've played the Wormhole exactly this way. And it would be nice to find any clues in the official rules of FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

I've been convinced this answer is wrong, but I'm leaving it for posterity until I see an official ruling.

You place the token on an ice protecting HQ. The subroutine is being resolved on Wormhole, not Builder. I couldn't find an exact ruling on this question, but [it's been ruled](http://ancur.wikia.com/wiki/Wormhole_and_Bioroid_Subroutines_Ruling) that the click ability on Bioroid Ice can't be used when Wormhole resolves one of their subroutines, and I think my answer here is a fair extension of that logic. Only if the ability referenced the Ice it lives on by name (e.g. [Data Raven](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01088)) should it not be referencing Wormhole (or in this case, the server Wormhole is protecting).

Comment: You say, that subroutine resolves on the Wormhole. But the text on it literally says "resolve a subroutine on another piece of rezzed ice". On another peice of rezzed ice! Not on Wormhole. To be resolved on the Wormhole, the text sould be something like "resolve a subrounite form another... on Wormhole"?

Comment: Bioroid click clause concerns only breaking subroutines and has nothing to do with resolving them. I believe, this situation is closer to Bifrost Array, which has similar wording and triggers agenda ability relative to *that agenda*

Comment: Hmm, I find your logics appealing.

Comment: All subroutines the runner wants to break are broken before the first one resolves, so by the time wormhole triggers the bioroid ice's subroutine, it's too late in the encounter to break any subs anyways, even if you could.